# Как отсортировать поле HierarchyId

Tags: c#, sql

Я сделал запрос на сортировку поля hierarchyId, но он как то не так сортирует. Даныне /214/1 и /214/2 встали не на свое место

```
select Path.ToString() as Nomer , 
        Path,
        Name, 
        Path.GetLevel() as Axixa  

from Users order by cast(Path as nvarchar(100)) ASC;



/1/1/
/1/2/
/1/3/
/2/1/
/2/2/
/2/3/
-/214/1/-
-/214/2/-
/3/1/1/
/3/1/2/
```

А должно быть так

```
/1/1/
/1/2/
/1/3/
/2/1/
/2/2/
/2/3/
/3/1/1/
/3/1/2/
/214/1/
/214/2/
```

Comment: А что ж вы хотите? Функционирует как написано. Если сортировать строки, то `2 < 214 < 3`. Сортируйте как числа.

Comment: ну так не дает сконвертировать в число. Говорит что hierarchyid нельзя сконвертировать в Int. Делал Path as int

Comment: А какого типа поле `hierarchyid` (и почему)?

Comment: поле hierarchyid типа hierarchyid))) пардон за тавтологию https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb677290.aspx

Comment: Окей, понял. А если отсортировать просто по самому `hierarchyid`?

Comment: Интересно)) все заработало. СПАСИБо!

Comment: тогда добавлю в ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы сортируете строковое представление. При сортировке строк вполне ожидаемо, что `2 < 214 < 3`. Сортируйте без приведения типов к строке.

---

(Не знал, что есть отдельный тип `hierarchyid`.)